# Deploy a .WAR to multiple Tomcat instances

Tags: tomcat, copy, cluster-computing, war, replicate

I have one .WAR to routinely deploy across various Tomcat Instances on different servers.

I believe FarmWarDeployer can only be used within a cluster. From what i understand, a cluster will require a HTTPD server with a mod_jk configured. Would anyone know of a way to achieve this without the need to configure a cluster? Ideally, i'd also like the context.xml to be distributable, so changing on one instance will update on all others...but i suspect this will require a cluster configured.

Any help/ideas appreciated!